# Include Subquery into SQL CASE Statement

Tags: mysql

Below query is used to get the number of Blocked test cases from ALM. Is it possible to include this query inside a CASE statement such that the output of the CASE Statement is "COUNT(LINK.LN_ENTITY_ID)"?

```
SELECT  BUG.BG_BUG_ID, COUNT(LINK.LN_ENTITY_ID) AS COUNT_TC, TESTCYCL.TC_STATUS FROM BUG
LEFT JOIN ALL_LISTS
ON BG_SUBJECT = AL_ITEM_ID
INNER JOIN LINK
ON BG_BUG_ID = LN_BUG_ID
LEFT JOIN TESTCYCL
ON TESTCYCL.TC_TEST_ID = LINK.LN_ENTITY_ID AND LINK.LN_ENTITY_TYPE = 'TESTCYCL'
WHERE TESTCYCL.TC_STATUS = 'Blocked'
GROUP BY BG_BUG_ID, TESTCYCL.TC_STATUS
```

Comment: pls mention table structure

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  BUG.BG_BUG_ID,
       SUM(CASE TESTCYCL.TC_STATUS WHEN ="Blocked" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT_TC,
       TESTCYCL.TC_STATUS
  FROM BUG
    LEFT JOIN ALL_LISTS
    ON BG_SUBJECT = AL_ITEM_ID
    INNER JOIN LINK
    ON BG_BUG_ID = LN_BUG_ID
    LEFT JOIN TESTCYCL
    ON TESTCYCL.TC_TEST_ID = LINK.LN_ENTITY_ID AND LINK.LN_ENTITY_TYPE = 'TESTCYCL'
    GROUP BY BG_BUG_ID
```

This query will display the total no. of bug with status=`"blocked"` for each `BUG_ID`.(Assuming that you need).

Hope this helps